# CakePHP Authcomponent session expires after using SSL unforce method

Tags: cakephp, ssl, cakephp-2.0

I am using SSL for 5 pages while during registration

> https://www.example.com/step1
> https://www.example.com/step2
> https://www.example.com/step3 - Auth component login
> https://www.example.com/step4
> https://www.example.com/step5

After step 3, I am creating a Session of the user using Auth Component which automatically logs the user in by Auth component. However, after step 5, it will redirect to http://www.example.com/welcome

I am using SSL component unforced method to change **HTTPS** to **HTTP** .
Everything working fine but the problem is that once I reach the welcome page from step 5 (HTTPS) my auth component session expires. I have tried to debug it, but could not find any solution. Please note that without HTTPS all steps and sessions are working fine.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969719/cakephp-cookie-session-problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Code in AppController class :***

```
function beforeFilter() {
parent::beforeFilter();
$this->_setupSecurity();}

function _setupSecurity() {
$this->Security->blackHoleCallback = '_badRequest';
if(Configure::read('forceSSL')) {
    $this->Security->requireSecure('*');    }
```

}

/**
* The main SecurityComponent callback.
* Handles both missing SSL problems and general bad requests.
*/

```
function _badRequest() {
if(Configure::read('forceSSL') && !$this->RequestHandler->isSSL()) {
    $this->_forceSSL();
} else {
    $this->cakeError('error400');
}
exit;}
```

/**
* Redirect to the same page, but with the https protocol and exit.
*/

```
function _forceSSL() {
$this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);
exit;
```

}

Follow this link: May be you get your solution..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4473178/983624

Answer (score 3):

if you are using Cakephp 2.0 then go to the following folder

lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/

Open the CakeSession.php file and search for the following line

```
if (!isset($sessionConfig['ini']['session.cookie_secure']) && env('HTTPS'))
{
        $sessionConfig['ini']['session.cookie_secure'] = 1; // Just comment this line and try it will works
}
```